# I can't relate between heap memory and OOP scopes

Tags: c++

I have class called Bob

```
class Bob 
{
   int lol;

 public:
   int* returnpointer()
   {
     lol = 4;
     return &lol;
   }
};

int main()
{
  Bob A = new Bob();
  int * pointertoprivate = A.returnpointer();
  *pointertoprivate = 10;
}
```

So my main should declare a new instance of Bob, get a pointer to a Private variable it shouldn't be accessing and change it. Is this possible? I didn't try to compile this.

Comment: Yes, that should work. BTW that's not going to compile, no - there's a few mistakes. At first glance: you don't need to `new int()`, or if you do you need to store it in an `int *`; you need a `class Bob` rather than just `Bob`; you dereference `pointertoprivate` the other way, `*pointertoprivate`; you've got the wrong brace to close the `Bob` class. And what's the question in the title - is that related?

Comment: This does not compile, please using [one of the many online compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) available if you don't have one locally.

Comment: Well sorry I am guessing I mixed a little of C# with my C++ code. I've used C# for quite a long time without understanding what's a heap and stack and I've just followed OOP scopes to write my stuff in.

Comment: Broadly, the heap is where newed and malloced objects go and the stack is where function local variables go. But the returned pointer could equally be on the stack: if you just did `Bob A();` then `A` would be allocated on the stack including the `lol`, and everything would still work.

Comment: @Rup: Except that `Bob A();` is a function declaration. I think you meant `Bob A;`

Comment: @MikeSeymour D'oh, sorry, yes - my C++ is pretty rusty too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access specifiers only restrict direct use of a name; they do not restrict indirect access to a member via a pointer. So your code does indeed allow `main` to modify a private member, since the member's name is only used with a member function.

<sub>(Or at least it would, if all the syntax errors were fixed)</sub>

This is the case whether or not the object is dynamically allocated (i.e. whether or not it's on the heap). In C++, you should get into the habit of avoiding `new` except where it's genuinely needed.